# Google Cloud Messaging XMPP Server with Node.js

Tags: node.js, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, node-xmpp

Title is fairly self explanatory. I need to create an XMPP server in Node.js to communicate with Google Cloud Messaging. The XMPP connection should allow me to send messages from the server to the client (Android app) and also from the app back to the server without the app needing a seperate socket connection to the server (all messages routed through GCM. Could anyone perhaps guide me in the right direction?

P.S. If I have provided insufficient information please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a simple Google search return that there is an XMPP server developed in NodeJS: https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-xmpp-server

This is likely what you want to deploy.

Comment: More specifically the node-gcm-ccs package had unmet dependancies whiles trying to install with "npm install node-gcm-ccs" which is the one I want to use ...